# What should I ask my designer for when I program for Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I'm new to Android development.
I'm trying to develop an app which includes many photos/icons/etc..
I have a designer friend, who designed my app. She has not experience in designing Android appications as well.

What kind of material does she need to provide me with?
I mean, she sent me a PDF where I see each screen of the app.

Now, do I need to get each photo/icon that is used in the design in a certain way?
Let's say, for each photo do I need to ask her to give me 4 versions: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi? anything else? should I ask for PNG formats?

What else do I need to receive from her in order to implement my app without bothering her anymore?

Thanks

Comment: **xxhdpi**, as well. and **xxxhdpi** in the future. OR you better use **SVG** files (you'll need a free library to use them).

Comment: yes ask her for pngs for four different versions..

Comment: svg and then you can use the new android studio's tool called vector assest and @ compile time you will get raster images for pre-lollipop and and on lollipop and above you can use vector drawables.

Comment: @Raghunandan Well, `VectorDrawables` are still very rough and only accept a **subset** of SVG (only the **path** directive has been implemented, so far)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein agree. I hear the google team is working on it and also vectordrawablcompat must be out soon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is preferable to ask for SVG instead of maintaining all the ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi ... images.
You should ask her following things:
According to screen wise : -

1. all the hex-colour codes.
2. if used any special fonts then .ttf, .otg files of those fonts.

I guess that is enough. I hope this helps :)

## Edit

Your Comment : - 
Thanks! can you elaborate on the "screen-wise"? do I have to get the svg for each screen size? There are a lot of screen size. Do you mean xlarge, large, normal and small?

There are Two options for you 1. Either user PNG or 2. use SVG just like Mr. Frank N. Stein has commented you need to user library for those. check out this [link](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/vector-graphics-in-android-part-1-svg/) for more info.

and by "screen-wise", I meant was, if your app has 3 screens then all the non-repeating images/icons you have to take those from your designer.
and if you choose to take PNG you need not worry about different sizes of the device and different image size required for those devices.

I hope this solves your doubt if not feel free to comment!!.

Comment: Thanks! can you elaborate on the "screen-wise"? do I have to get the svg for each screen size? There are a lot of screen size. Do you mean xlarge, large, normal and small?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't explain in detail in my answer.
I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. you don't need to ask your friend for all the images, it means for all the resolutions, you can only ask your friend for the higher resolution, just because once you will get that resolution from this you can make all three small resolutions mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi respectively.

Always note that higher resolution can generate lower resolutions but that's not possible to create lower  resolutions to higher resolutions.

So, you just need Xxhdpi icons and from it you can make the rest of all.